# Observable next does not emit

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this simple function to put file in S3:

```
putFile$(S3AuthorizationToken: S3AuthorizationToken, file: File) {
    const futureFile: FutureFile = {
      size: file.size,
      type: file.type,
    };

    return combineLatest([
      this.http.put(S3AuthorizationToken.signedUrl, file, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': file.type,
        }),
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
      }),
      of(futureFile),
    ]);
  }
}
```

In my component I want to listen for upload progress updates:

```
private percentChange = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
percentChange$ = this.percentChange.asObservable();

onFileChange(event: Event) {
    console.log(event);
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const file: File = target.files[0];

    this.s3
      .getS3AuthorizationToken$()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((S3AuthorizationToken) =>
          this.s3.putFile$(S3AuthorizationToken, file)
        ),
        map(([event, futureFile]) => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            const percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            console.log(`Uploading ${percent}%`);
            this.percentChange.next(percent);
          }
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log(`Upload complete`);
            this.futureFile.next(futureFile);
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

The problem I've encountered is with `this.percentChange.next()` and `this.futureFile.next()`

It seem not to emit any value.

In my template I have:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">

<div>{{ percentChange$ | async | json }} %</div>
```

Do you have any idea what can cause this?

Comment: try to put `return` statement `return this.http.put(S3AuthorizationToken.signedUrl, file, {...}` and check.

Answer (score 0):

You might actually have to map to the `this.s3.putFile$(S3AuthorizationToken, file)` observable directly instead of the response returned from the `switchMap`. Try the following

```js
onFileChange(event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const file: File = target.files[0];

  this.s3.getS3AuthorizationToken$().pipe(
    switchMap((S3AuthorizationToken) =>
      this.s3.putFile$(S3AuthorizationToken, file).pipe(
        map(([event, futureFile]) => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            const percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            console.log(`Uploading ${percent}%`);
            this.percentChange.next(percent);
          } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log(`Upload complete`);
            this.futureFile.next(futureFile);
          }
          return event;      // <-- return something for the `map` operator
        })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe();
}
```